# Can I match regular expressions in switch statements in R?

Tags: r, regex, switch-statement, stringr

I have a vector of string where people where asked to guess someones age, this includes statements like "50-60", "ca. 50" or ">50". I want to use regular expressions to match these cases and get the real numerical values. "50-60" should produce 55 (as the mean of both values), the other two examples 50.

For each variant, I wanted to have a case in a switch like below, but it doesn't seem to work. Is it even possible to use a regex in a switch?

```r
switch (string,
          str_detect(string, "[:digit:]+[:blank:]*(-|_)[:blank:]*[:digit:]+") = {
            first <- str_sub(string, 1, 2) %>% as.numeric()
            second <- str_sub(string, str_length(string)-1, str_length(string)) %>% as.numeric()
            value <- mean(c(first, second))
          },
          str_detect(string, "((ca)\.?)|>|~[:blank:]*[:digit:]+") = {
            value <- str_sub(string, str_length(string)-1, str_length(string)) %>% as.numeric()
          },
          str_detect(string, "[:digit:]+[:punct:]") = {
            value <- str_sub(string, 1, 2) %>% as.numeric()
          },
          print(string, " could not be matched")
  )
```

The expressions themselves are working as intended (as far as I tested), so I guess I can't use them in the switch like this. However I couldn't find a solution anywhere.

Edit: Added what the expected output for the examples is

Comment: pleae add some relevant sample data and desired output.

Comment: Examples were already in the text, but I added the expected output for those.

Comment: No, you can't do that in `switch`.  It's just a function, and the LHS of `arg = expr` in a function call has to be a name, not a logical expression.  The `dplyr::case_when` function is set up to allow a sequence of logical expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with [`tidyverse`](https://www.tidyverse.org/) methods

1. Convert the string to a `tibble/data.frame`
2. Remove the characters not neeeded with [`str_remove_all`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/1.4.0/topics/str_remove)
3. Then, [`separate`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tidyr/versions/1.1.3/topics/separate) the column into two by specifying the `sep`
4. Get the `rowMeans`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
tibble(mystring) %>%
    mutate(mystring = str_remove_all(mystring, "[A-Za-z.><]+")) %>% 
    separate(mystring, into = c('col1', 'col2'), sep="[- ]+", 
         convert = TRUE) %>%
    transmute(out = rowMeans(., na.rm = TRUE))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 1
    out
  <dbl>
1    55
2    50
3    50
```

#### data

```
mystring <- c("50-60", "ca. 50", ">50")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested `if`/`else` approach -

```
library(stringr)

string <- "50-60"

if(str_detect(string, "[:digit:]+[:blank:]*(-|_)[:blank:]*[:digit:]+")) {
          first <- str_sub(string, 1, 2) %>% as.numeric()
          second <- str_sub(string, str_length(string)-1, str_length(string)) %>% as.numeric()
          value <- mean(c(first, second))
          value
        } else if(str_detect(string, "((ca)\\.?)|>|~[:blank:]*[:digit:]+")) {
          value <- str_sub(string, str_length(string)-1, str_length(string)) %>% as.numeric()
          value
        } else if(str_detect(string, "[:digit:]+[:punct:]")) {
          value <- str_sub(string, 1, 2) %>% as.numeric()
          value
        } else NA

#[1] 55
```

For `string <- "ca. 50"` it returns 50.

Answer (score 0):

```
mystring <- c("50-60", "ca. 50", ">50")

library(stringr)
lapply(str_extract_all(mystring, "[0-9]+"), 
       function(x) if (length(x) == 1) as.numeric(x[1]) else mean(as.numeric(x)))
[[1]]
[1] 55

[[2]]
[1] 50

[[3]]
[1] 50
```